# Magento Coupon codes although deleted already, doesn't allow to create coupon with same code again

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, coupon-codes, price-rules

I am not sure if it's some kind of core-logic(unknown to me) or a bug maybe, but even though I have already deleted a coupon-code rule from "Shopping Cart Price Rules", when I search in the "salesrule_coupon" table the deleted coupon code, it still shows up.

What happens due to above scenario is that if I try to recreate the coupon-rule with same code, it doesn't allow me to do so and shows below message:

```
Coupon with the same code already exists.
```

Please enlighten me anyone and let me know how to delete coupon-rule with code completely and uniquely, so I can create coupon with same code again.

My magento version is ce-1.9.0.1

Comment: I can't reproduce this in 1.9.2.1 - I create the coupon rule with coupon TESTCOUPON, apply the coupon to cart to test it. Delete the coupon rule, reset cart. Add the coupon rule again with the same coupon name TESTCOUPON. I see no errors.

Answer (score 0):

If its not showing up anywhere else other than the table, I would change it in the table -- not delete it -- to something unique.  Maybe put a few numbers at the end.  Random stuff.  That should take care of it.